# How to recognize id?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have one table in which I have Ids stored in comma separated.
For example, For Customer it is 3 and for Material it is 5.
Then it will be stored as 3,5

Now in another table, I have values for that particular ID
For example, Customer with ID 40, and material with ID 1
Then it is stored as 40,1

Now when fetching this data, how will I know which customer and which material.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Alter your structure and divide the data to separate columns. This may be generated columns, for example. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=fcda35a1cedeaa3e3b08f2657418023c

Comment: You have multiple tables where customer,material are stored as csv? - Bad idea on both counts but if only 2 values in csv split them using substring_index

Comment: I know it's probably too late, but I can't understand why that design is so popular. You combine the speed of relational databases and the data integrity and search capabilities of flat files.

Comment: nb you cannot index on either customer or material so query performance is going to suffer and you cannot add foreign key constraints

Comment: Given the above and a comment you've added to [this answer](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/container) where you say the 'owner' could be a `User` or `Company` you should seriously reconsider your table design choice as this is quickly going to get out of hand, become unmanagable and unscalable.

Comment: From the comment in the posted ansewer 'It can be different also. Like Company and Material OR Customer, Company and Material. So that is upto user which combination he wants' - in that case no chance - there is no way of knowing what each node means. Consider json as an alternative datatype.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Neha
Just make a global function that will accept the value.
As you already know first value is the customer and the second value is for the material.
Just split your values by considering comma is your key.

Simple.

On the other hand, if you have relations of customers and the materials ID on other tables then you should need to change your approach by storing these values in separate columns.

Comment: It can be different also. Like Company and Material OR Customer, Company and Material.
So that is upto user which combination he wants.